# TypeOrm Do I need to useTransaction when updating an entity with multiple one to many relations

Tags: transactions, sql-update, nestjs, typeorm

I have a Company class with the following definition:

```
export class Company extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field((type) => ID) // needed to overwrite the number typ
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  domain: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.company, {
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  })
  users: User[];

  @OneToMany(() => Deal, (deal) => deal.company)
  deals: Deal[];
}
```

and when updating a company, the update company dto would contain both a list of dealIds as well as userIds to add to the existing relations. Here is my update method:

```
async update(id: number, updateCompanyInput: UpdateCompanyInput) {
    console.log(`This action updates a #${id} company`);
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();

    const company = await queryRunner.manager.preload(Company, {
      id,
      ...updateCompanyInput,
    });
    
    await queryRunner.manager
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .relation(Company, 'users')
      .of(id)
      .add(updateCompanyInput.userIds);

    await queryRunner.manager
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .relation(Company, 'deals')
      .of(id)
      .add(updateCompanyInput.dealIds);

    const result = this.companyRepository.save(company);
    await queryRunner.release();
    return result;
  }
```

I am wondering:

1. Do I need to use a transaction (https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions)?
2. Do I need to call `queryRunner.release()` after `this.companyRepository.save` or the order can be more flexible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not **need** to use a transaction. You should use a transaction if and only if you want to undo the added `Company, 'users'` relation when something goes wrong adding the `Company, 'deals'` relation. Transactions are just a way of making the queries within it **atomic** (ie all occur or none occur).

As far as query runner releasing - I'm not sure. I haven't used query runner at all. I'm not sure why you are, actually, so maybe this is a bad answer? I use `getRepository` for everything. ie either
`getRepository(Company).createQueryBuilder('company')`

Or

`getRepository(Company).find('primary key value')`

should both work, assuming you create the connection on server startup.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Sounds to me like transactions are a best practice though right? Since atomic is generally considered "best practice" I assume?

Comment: I have typically used `transaction`  https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions but Query Runner seems even better.